# Tracking changes in version control: Github vs. Azure DevOps

Tags: github

We're thinking of changing over from Azure DevOps to Github for our Version control. One feature in Azure DevOps that we use a lot is tracking which user committed each change. Is there a way to track that in Github? Which user committed/pushed each change to the master branch?

Answer (score 0):

stack, short answer is Yes, GitHub has a way to track which user's are committing changes. One of the best ways to do this is through pull requests.

More information on the differences between the two can be found here:
[https://www.upguard.com/blog/microsoft-visual-studio-team-services-vs-github#:~:text=The%20most%20obvious%2C%20classic%20distinction,between%20public%2Fprivate%20development%20modes](https://www.upguard.com/blog/microsoft-visual-studio-team-services-vs-github#:%7E:text=The%20most%20obvious%2C%20classic%20distinction,between%20public%2Fprivate%20development%20modes).